# Error! phone is too short or empty (EBS integration)

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, prestashop-1.5

I am using prestashop 1.5.5.0 and using fashion bird theme in it. Now I am experiencing a problem during the redirection to payment page. Its showing a error " Phone is too short or empty".

But I noticed one thing that this error is not showing during INSTANT CHECKOUT.

The error is showing only during the registered user checkout. I notice one thing also during registration process, the form is submission works smoothly even the required field "phone number" is not filled.

I guess that the the payment gateway is not getting the phone number along with address when registered user makes a checkout.

My domain is   [http//:thriti.com][1]

I am using EBS payment gateway.

I hope anybody will give a solution for my problem as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Minimum length for shipping or billing phone number is 5 digits/chars.